# Saving the result of a SQL query into a local SQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below code that is not working as expected:

```
DECLARE @MySelect varchar(max), @MyRecipients varchar(max), @MyId 
char(4),@MyResult varchar(max);


SET @MyId = '1';
SET @MySelect = 'SELECT SQL_Script FROM AutoSendMail.dbo.A01_St WHERE 
ID =' + @MyId; 


USE msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='Operator',
@recipients='Mail@test.com',
@subject='Mail test',
@body= 'This is a test-mail',
@mailitem_id='1',
@query= @MyResult, 
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
```

I need to save the result of the select query: `@MySelect` into the variable `@MyResult`, because I need to send the result of the `SELECT` via Mail. But I can't find a way to do just that. The query should return a single string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without dynamic SQL, like so:

```
DECLARE @MyRecipients VARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @MyId CHAR(4) = '1' ,
    @MyResult VARCHAR(MAX);


SET @MyId = '1';

SELECT TOP 1
        @MyResult = SQL_Script
FROM    AutoSendMail.dbo.A01_St
WHERE   ID = @MyId


USE msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Operator', @recipients = 'Mail@test.com',
    @subject = 'Mail test', @body = 'This is a test-mail', @mailitem_id = '1',
    @query = @MyResult, @attach_query_result_as_file = 1
```

Not that you need dynamic SQL, but please note, that doing this:

```
SET @MySelect = 'SELECT SQL_Script FROM AutoSendMail.dbo.A01_St WHERE ID =' + @MyId;
```

Does not execute any code, it simply sets the value of `@MySelect`. You would need to call an execute command to run the SQL:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @MySelect
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare table variable, insert into it the results of executing your query and then select into your result variable:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(SQL_Script varchar(max))
INSERT INTO @t EXEC(@MySelect)
SELECT TOP 1 @MyResult = SQL_Script FROM @t
```

You can also use `sp_executesql` procedure with output parameters like:

```
SET @MyId = '1';
SET @MySelect = 'SELECT @MyResult = SQL_Script FROM AutoSendMail.dbo.A01_St WHERE 
ID =' + @MyId; 

EXEC sp_executesql @MySelect, '@MyResult varchar(max) OUTPUT', @MyResult OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select  @MyResult = stuff((
                           select  ',' + convert(nvarchar(20), SQL_Script)
                           from    AutoSendMail.dbo.A01_St
                           where   ID = @MyId
                           for
                           xml path('')
                           ), 1, 1, '')
```

This outputs a comma delimited string though